# How native is an app created with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been asking myself this for a long time: Are the applications created with Flutter 100% Native? The performance of a Flutter app can be equal to or better than an app created with Java / Kotlin? Many people are saying that the applications created with flutter are not really native, they are hybrid or similar, and I have read the same in some places on the internet, so I would like to read what you say, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what your definition of "native" is.

To some people, "native" means using the UI widgets provided by the OS.

Flutter applications are "native" in the sense that they are compiled to native machine instructions rather than being interpreted by a VM.  For Android and iOS apps, that means that they are compiled to ARM code.

From a fidelity standpoint, this does mean that Flutter UI widgets might not look or behave quite the same as the OS's UI widgets.  From a performance standpoint, however, Flutter UI widgets can be as (or possibly *more*) performant than the OS's.

Further reading: [Pitching Flutter to your company or client: 3. Native Apps](https://medium.com/flutter-io/https-medium-com-flutter-io-pitching-flutter-2d4f494e47d1#9f9e)

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, native app is better than flutter in terms of performance.

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/examining-performance-differences-between-native-flutter-and-react-native-mobile-development

So I guess the question to your answer would be no, but Flutter is definitely a "good enough solution" for most cases. There wouldn't be a case where you will be able to notice the difference in performance by human unless you are developing a super cpu intensive app.

Comment: Note that the article you cited had a flaw in the comparison.  The differences are smaller in [the updated version of the article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/examining-performance-differences-between-native-flutter-and-react-native-mobile-development-take-two).

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for the update. I guess the conclusion of flutter being slightly worse than native doesn't really change though.